# How do I left join tables in unidirectional many-to-one in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-one

I'm piggy-backing off of [How to join tables in unidirectional many-to-one condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368195/how-to-join-tables-in-unidirectional-many-to-one-condition).

If you have two classes:

```
class A {
    @Id
    public Long id;
}

class B {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public A parent;
}
```

B -> A is a many to one relationship.  I understand that I could add a Collection of Bs to A however I do not want that association.

**So my actual question is, Is there an HQL or Criteria way of creating the SQL query:**

```
select * from A left join B on (b.parent_id = a.id)
```

This will retrieve all A records with a Cartesian product of each B record that references A and will include A records that have no B referencing them.

If you use:

```
from A a, B b where b.a = a
```

then it is an inner join and you do not receive the A records that do not have a B referencing them.

I have not found a good way of doing this without two queries so anything less than that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: @Joe B And what you want is... ???

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: I need a Criteria or HQL way of making the raw SQL query I wrote above.  I've edited the post to bold the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an example with what you posted and I think this may work:

`select a,b from B as b left outer join b.parent as a` in HQL.

I have to find a "criteria" way of doing that though.

Comment: Maybe THIS one would do the trick: 
select a, b from B as b right join b.parent as a

Comment: I didn't think of a right join.  As long as HQL supports right joins and I'm only using a few tables that might work.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You may do so by specifying the fetch attribute.

> (10) fetch (optional) Choose between outer-join fetching and fetching by sequential select.

You find it at: [Chapter 6. Collection Mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/collections.html), scroll down to: *6.2. Mapping a Collection*

**EDIT**

I read in your question's comment that you wanted a way to perform a raw SQL query? Here a reference that might possibly be of interest:

[Chapter 13 - Native SQL Queries](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/querysql.html)

and if you want a way to make it possible through HQL:

[Chapter 11. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html)

In chapter 11, you want to scroll down to **11.3. Associations and joins**.

```
IQuery q = session.CreateQuery(@"from A as ClassA left join B as ClassB");
```

I guess however that ClassB needs to be a member of ClassA. Further reasdings shall help.

Another thing that might proove to be useful to you are [named queries](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/17/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-lt-query-gt-and-lt-sql-query-gt.aspx):

```
<query name="PeopleByName">
from Person p
where p.Name like :name
</query>
```

And calling this query from within code like so:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) {
        session.GetNamedQuery("PeopleByName")
            .SetParameter("name", "ayende")
            .List();
        tx.Commit();
    }
```

Please take a look at the referenced link by Ayende who explains it more in depth.

Comment: I do not want to map the collection of B in A.  I need a query without the mapped collection.